# how to communicate two webworkers html5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-worker

I am going through webworkers documentation, I cant find any api that support communication between two webworkers. Here is my context, now i need to communicate worker1 with worker2 directly? not from UI. its just like thread messaging.

app.js

```
var worker1 = new Worker("worker1.js");
var worker2 = new Worker("worker2.js");

worker1.onmessage=function(e) {
   console.log("msg from worker1"+e.data);
}
worker1.postMessage("ping worker1");

worker2.onmessage=function(e) {
   console.log("msg from worker2"+e.data);
}
worker2.postMessage("ping worker2");
```

worker1.js

```
onmessage=function(e) {
   postMessage(e.data)
}
```

worker2.js

```
onmessage=function(e) {
   postMessage(e.data)
}
```

1. Is it possible ?
2. does any HTML5 API support it?
3. if support how can I implement direct communication?

If it is possible please paste some example to do it.

Comment: See about `MessageChannel` (although, not many good examples). If not, you can always communicate indirectly by dispatching through main thread.

Comment: I saw it but i cant understood how to do it?

Comment: @amadan please paste some sample stuff using MessageChannel

Comment: Sorry, not an expert there; this is the best I could find: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html#shared-workers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution after working some time on MessageChannel. Here is [demo of working link](http://www.antkorp.in/workersComm/)